# Should we write `std::move` in the cases when RVO can not be done?

Tags: c++, return-value, move-semantics, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

It is known that `std::move` should not be applied to the function return values because it can prevent RVO (return value optimization). I am interested in the question what should we do if we certainly know that RVO will not happen.

This is what the C++14 standard says [12.8/32]

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but
>   not for an exception-declaration, and the object to be copied is
>   designated by an lvalue, or when the expression in a return statement
>   is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with
>   automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>   parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or
>   lambda-expression, overload resolution to select the constructor for
>   the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an
>   rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed,
>   or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is
>   not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified),
>   overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an
>   lvalue. [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed
>   regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the
>   constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected
>   constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. — end note
>   ]

Here is the explanation from the book `Effective Modern C++`

> The part of the Standard blessing the RVO goes on to say that if the
>   conditions for the RVO are met, but compilers choose not to perform
>   copy elision, the object being returned must be treated as an rvalue.
>   In effect, the Standard requires that when the RVO is permitted,
>   either copy elision takes place or std::move is implicitly applied to
>   local objects being returned

As I understand when return object can't be elided at first it should be regarded as `rvalue`. In these example we can see that when we pass argument greater than `5` object is moved otherwise it is copied. Does it mean that we should explicitly write `std::move` when we know that RVO will not happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Test
{
    Test() {}

    Test(const Test& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Test(const Test&)" << std::endl;
    }

    Test(Test&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Test(const Test&&)" << std::endl;
    }
};

Test foo(int param)
{
    Test test1;
    Test test2;
    return param > 5 ? std::move(test1) : test2;
}

int main()
{
    Test res = foo(2);
}
```

The output of this program is `Test(const Test&)`.

Comment: "*As I understand when return object can't be elided at first it should be regarded as `rvalue`*" As long as the conditions for copy elision are met (or they would be met except the object is a function parameter.)

Comment: Are you also interested in C++17 answers?

Comment: If using std::move does it move the local to the temporary on the right side of the equals sign and then further call either copy or move constructor?

Comment: @Yakk I just want to understand what is going here. It is recommended not to write `std::move` on return values but in this example it would be copied it I not write it. It I change `?` operator to `if` it would always moved...

Comment: @juanchopanza object is not function parameter so do copy elision conditions are met? Why it is copied in that case?

Comment: @ashot you have no move on the return value in your example.  You have one *in* the return value expression.  So, I do not know what you do not understand.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return std::move(param > 5 ? test1 : test2);`? (since test1 and test2 are of the same type, the result of that ternary expression is a reference, which is not the case in your example)

Comment: Generally no and unless you are performing a type conversion `return std::move(...)` is pointless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What happen in your example is not linked to RVO, but to the ternary `operator ?`. If you rewrite your example code using an `if` statement, the behavior of the program will be the one expected. Change `foo` definition to:

```
Test foo(int param)
  {
  Test test1;
  Test test2;
  if (param > 5)
    return std::move(test2);
  else
    return test1;
  }
```

will output `Test(Test&&)`.

---

What happens if you write `(param>5)?std::move(test1):test2` is:

1. The ternary operator result is deduced to be a *prvalue* [[expr.cond]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#5)
2. Then `test2` pass through [*lvalue-to-rvalue*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/conv.lval#2.4) conversion which causes [copy-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#15) as required in [[expr.cond]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#6)
3. Then the move construction of the return value is elided [[class.copy]/31.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#31.3)

So in your example code, move elision occurs, nevertheless after the copy-initialization required to form the result of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in your example the copy elision is happened. If you explicitly forbid RVO/NRVO with the argument `-fno-elide-constructors`, then it possibly print (I used Apple clang version 13.0.0 and Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_2)

```
Test(const Test&)
Test(const Test&&)
Test(const Test&&)
```

The first copy constructor is called in order to evaluate expression `param > 5 ? std::move(test1) : test2`. And the move constructor will be called at least once since copy elision is unavailable. So I think add `std::move` on return statement is always superfluous.